# Calculated Column formula to find two values in column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a Single Line Text Column(Content). I would like to create a calculated column that returns "Yes" if the Content column contains either of the two words- "Urgent" or"Date".

I have only managed to create the formula that returns "Yes" if the column contains "Urgent". How do I find for either of the two words?

Current formula:
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Urgent",Content)),"Yes","No")

Answer (score 0):

Extending your current formula slightly should do the trick:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Urgent",Content)),"Yes",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Date",Content)),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an OR statement:
`=IF(OR(Content="Urgent",Content="Date"),"Yes","No")`